Why is Next.js throwing Error: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE is not a function?
I'm unable to figure out the problem. I'm exporting a function that serves the current authenticated user object (if present). I'm then using this user object to determine the addition of a nav link. This error won't go away no matter how much I've reformed the reference.
This is the function definition @/app/hooks/use-auth-user.ts
'use client';
import {
    fetchAuthSession,
    fetchUserAttributes,
    getCurrentUser,
} from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function UseAuthUser() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<Record<string, any>>();

useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser() {
        const session = await fetchAuthSession();
        if (!session.tokens) {
            return;
        }

        const user = {
            ...(await getCurrentUser()),
            ...(await fetchUserAttributes()),
            isAdmin: false,
        };

        const groups = session.tokens.accessToken.payload['cognito:groups'];
        // @ts-ignore
        user.isAdmin = Boolean(groups && groups.includes('administrators'));
        setUser(user);
    }

    getUser();
}, []);

return user;
}

And Here is the function that I'm referencing it from @/app/lib/menus.ts
import UseAuthUser from '@/app/hooks/use-auth-user';

export function getResourceMenu(): Menu {
const user = UseAuthUser();
let links: Menu = [
    { name: 'Privacy Policy', href: '/privacy' },
    { name: 'Terms & Conditions', href: '/terms-and-conditions' },
    { name: 'Member Portal', href: '/auth/login' },
];

if (user) {
    links.push({ name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard' });
}

return links;
}

I'm attaching a screenshot of the error here:
Error: (0 , _app_hooks_use_auth_user__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default) is not a function


I'd love some input on where I'm going wrong here because obviously - I am.

How are you importing UseAuthUser ? This function name should follow camelCase though

@Mike I initially used camel case and encountered the same problem. I capitalized it thinking that maybe that was the issue but I was still wrong. I'm going to update the post with the import statement

Actually, the error WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE indicates you are importing a module that is intended for backend (or possibly the other way around). Also, my suggestion for your function name is more about convention, you're not forced to, it's for our understanding

I tried to reproduce your issue and stumbled upon a different one. By resolving this one, I could run the code with no issues, which perhaps should solve your issue too.

The issue here is that use-auth-user hook is marked as a client-only module using use client. Which means it can be used only within client components.
However, the getResourceMenu() function in menus.ts is calling UseAuthUser() directly, which is being treated as a server code, causing a mismatch.
I moved on and refactored the code to make it run successfully to resolve this  particular issue and it seems to resolve yours one as well.
Moving the logic to a client component
Here, UseAuthUser is called in a client component and the result is handed over to getResourceMenu instead of a direct hook call inside of getResourceMenu function.
// src/components/MenuComponent.tsx
'use client';  // Mark this as a client component
import React from 'react';
import UseAuthUser from '@/hooks/use-auth-user';
import { getResourceMenu } from '@/lib/menus';

const MenuComponent = () => {
    const user = UseAuthUser();  // Fetch user on the client side
    const links = getResourceMenu(user);  // Pass user data to getResourceMenu

    return (
        <nav>
            {links.map((link, index) => (
                <a key={index} href={link.href}>
                    {link.name}
                </a>
            ))}
        </nav>
    );
};

export default MenuComponent;

Changes to getResourceMenu
Just accepting user as an input and apply conditional rendering
export function getResourceMenu(user: any) {
    let links = [
        { name: 'Privacy Policy', href: '/privacy' },
        { name: 'Terms & Conditions', href: '/terms-and-conditions' },
    ];

    if (user) {
        links.push({ name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard' });
    }

    return links;
}


You're exactly right that was the issue. I'm not sure why I didn't get as clear a message as you did but once I stopped referencing the useAuthUser() function from the server it worked just fine. Thanks mate!
